# can we share Firebase Test Lab Results

Tags: firebase-test-lab

How to share Performance graph of network, Memory, and Cpu using Test lab instead of sending the screenshot to my client.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way to give direct access to your reports is to add your client as a view on the Firebase project via [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview).